# Echo numbering counter - remove leading zeros

Tags: php, echo, counter

At the moment I have a numbering system that brings back the following:

Using:

```
<?php echo $slide->counter; ?>
```

**01 02 03 04 05**

What can I add to the above php to get rid of the zero, so that it displays:

**1 2 3 4 5**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work...

```
printf('%d', $slide->counter);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo (int)$slider->counter; ?>
```

Comment: Casting to an int won't allow 0's?

Comment: @tubaguy50035: Casting it to int will eliminate any prefixing 0s.

Comment: Ah.  Didn't understand the question.